# Vertical tab inside the modal not displayed properly in different browser

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display a vertical tab inside a Bootstrap 4 Modal. But the same modal is displayed differently in google chrome and firefox browser.

Code i am using:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-4">Bootstrap Modals</h1>
  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h3>The Large Modal</h3>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">Click to open Modal</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- large modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Large Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Modal Body</h3>

          <div class="container">
            <div class="row mt-4">
              <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">amet consectetur</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false"> nobis et, tempora pl</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <h2>Home</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, eveniet earum. Sed accusantium eligendi molestiae quo hic velit nobis et, tempora placeat ratione rem blanditiis voluptates vel ipsam? Facilis, earum!</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                    <h2>Profile</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, eveniet earum. Sed accusantium eligendi molestiae quo hic velit nobis et, tempora placeat ratione rem blanditiis voluptates vel ipsam? Facilis, earum!</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, eveniet earum. Sed accusantium eligendi molestiae quo hic velit nobis et, tempora placeat ratione rem blanditiis voluptates vel ipsam? Facilis, earum!</p>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Popper JS -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Screen in Chrome]

[image: Screen in Firefox]

It is seen that in `col-md-2` if the length of that text is longer than in chrome it gets wrapped automatically, but incase of firefox it doesn't get wrapped properly.

But What could be the reason being the design look weird in firefox? How to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is faulty in that the modal body element begins *inside* the modal header element. They should be siblings. A good editor with auto-formatting (or disciplined self-formatting) would reveal this. You're missing three closing div tags in total.

Simply adding closing div tags to the modal header and outer modal elements result in changes to the layout, including proper layout for mobile. The reason you saw differences between browsers is because each attempted to correct your flaws in different ways.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-4">Bootstrap Modals</h1>

  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h3>The Large Modal</h3>

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">Click to open Modal</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- large modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Large Modal</h4>

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">amet consectetur</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false"> nobis et, tempora pl</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                  <h2>Home</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, eveniet earum. Sed accusantium eligendi molestiae quo hic velit nobis et, tempora placeat ratione rem blanditiis voluptates vel ipsam? Facilis, earum!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                  <h2>Profile</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, eveniet earum. Sed accusantium eligendi molestiae quo hic velit nobis et, tempora placeat ratione rem blanditiis voluptates vel ipsam? Facilis, earum!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                  <h2>Contact</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, eveniet earum. Sed accusantium eligendi molestiae quo hic velit nobis et, tempora placeat ratione rem blanditiis voluptates vel ipsam? Facilis, earum!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```